# When to use bias in Keras model?

Tags: keras, neural-network, deep-learning, hyperparameters, bias-neuron

I am new to modeling with Keras. I am trying to evaluate appropriate parameters for setting up the model. How do I know when you use bias vs when to turn it off?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is, always use bias variables when your model is small. Otherwise, it is still recommended to keep using bias in all neural network architectures.

Because each neurone performs like a simple logistic regression. In each neurone, the input values are multiplied with by the weights and the bias affects the initial level in the sigmoid function, which results the desired the non-linearity.

For example, if you have a zero input in your training data like `X = [[0,0,...], [0,0,...],... ] , Y = 1`, in a sigmoid function, the output will always be exactly `Y=0.5` since `X*W` is zero. However, in large networks, each node  can make a bias node out of the average activation of all of its inputs.